# delta function as density w.r.t. counting measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, dirac-delta, radon-nikodym

As we know, the delta function is not a Radon-Nikodym density with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

If we choose the counting measure $\mu$, which assigns to every set the number of its elements, then the delta function should be a density.

But how do we compute this integral then: $$\int \delta(x) d\mu(x) = \int_{\{x=0\}} \delta(x) d\mu(x)$$

How can this be evaluated to make sense?

Comment: It doesn't make so much sense as written. The way it could be seen it's as $\mu\{0\}$...

Comment: @Surb: Can $\delta(x)$ be interpreted as $1_{x=0}$. Then it would make sense?

Comment: Depend on the context, but normally $\delta $ is a measure not a function. But in your context, I wouldn't be surprised that $\delta $ is indeed seen as the function $\boldsymbol 1_{\{x=0\}}$.

Comment: But how is this possible since the delta function is in some sense the derivative of such a step function?

Comment: As I said, what you call "delta-"function is not a function, but a distribution (or also can be seen as a measure). After it's indeed the derivative of some distribution (and in the distribution sense), but it's not the derivative of a function in the "usual sense".